# How to query software packages that I installed today?

Tags: package-management

How to query software packages that I installed today or yestoday ?

Comment: Open software center and see history.

Answer (score 1):

The below awk oneliner command will displays all the packages that are installed today or yesterday,

```
awk -v foo=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d') -v bar=$(date -d "yesterday" '+%Y-%m-%d') '($1==foo || $1==bar) && $3~/^install$/ { print $4 }' /var/log/dpkg.log
```

**Explanation:**

1. `-v` -> Values assigned to the awk variables are done through `-v` parameter. Syntax would be, `-v variable=value` . This variable is used by awk for further purposes.
2. `foo=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d') -v bar=$(date -d "yesterday" '+%Y-%m-%d')`

   - `date '+%Y-%m-%d'`, prints the current date. The output of this command is assigned to the variable `foo` .
   - `date -d "yesterday" '+%Y-%m-%d'`, prints the yesterday's date. Again it's output is stored as value to the variable `var`.
3. `'($1==foo || $1==bar) && $3~/^install$/ { print $4 }'`

   - `||`->logical OR operator, `&&` -> logical AND operator.
   - `($1==foo || $1==bar) && $3~/^install$/` -> Checks if the value in the column number 1 matches the value of variable `foo`(*which contains current date*) **OR** the column number 1 matches the value of `bar`(*which contains yesterday's date*) **AND** there must be a string `install` present in the column number 3. If these conditions are satisfied, awk prints the value of column 4 (*package name*).
4. `/var/log/dpkg.log` -> Input file.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the apt logs in your favorite text viewer, they are located at `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command to query the installed package with specific date:

```
$ grep install /var/log/dpkg.log.1 | grep <yyyy-mm-dd> //specify date that you want to check.

e.g

$grep install /var/log/dpkg.log.1 | grep "2014-04-22"
```

Answer (score 0):

use this script :

```
#!/bin/bash
today=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
yesterday=$(date -d "yesterday" '+%Y-%m-%d')
echo 'today : '$today
grep $today < /var/log/apt/history.log -A2 | grep Install | cut -d':' -f2
echo 'yesterday : '$yesterday
grep $yesterday < /var/log/apt/history.log -A2 | grep Install | cut -d':' -f2
```